# SharePoint not finding a user I want to add to a site

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, ssp

I've just installed MOSS2007 onto a new development server. I've created an SSP and done a successfull crawl of our domain. I've created a web application and a blank site collection and am trying to add a user into the site owners. In the add users box I type his full login name, including domain prefix and click the little check names button but it doesn't find him. Nor will it find him if I browse and search. I tried my own domain login and it couldn't find that either (currently logged on as local administrator). I added all authenticated users to the site visitors, logged off the site and logged on with my domain login, which worked. I switch back to administrator on the site and try to add my domain user to the site, which now works, but only me.

1. Why doesn't SharePoint lookup the user from the SSP where it has been imported too.
2. Why does it only start to find a particular user once they've logged on, but not before.

Comment: I should note that I've done SharePoint dev machine installs before and not had this problem. I can't figure out why it's not working properly this time around, and what I did differently to cause it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You cannot add a domain user while logged in as a local administrator, since the local administrator does not have access to the domain.
- Once you log on to the machine your credentials are cached and the local administrator has access to them

You should administer sharepoint using a domain user.